# Methods 'add' of object 'SlicerCaches' failed error

Tags: excel, vba

So I created two pivot tables from the same source. What i want to do is to create a `SlicerCache` to connect these two tables together. The code run successfully in **Excel 2010** and **Excel 2013** but failed in **Excel 2016**.

Here is my code to create the first pivot table:

```
Sub OneYearTrend(wb As Workbook, wk As Worksheet)
With wb
    Dim pvc As PivotCache
    'Creat pivotcache
    Set pvc = .PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, wk.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, xlPivotTableVersion14)
    Dim pvt As PivotTable


    'Create pivot table for new hire and separation

    Set pvt = pvc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("M6"), _
                            TableName:="OneYear_pvTbl_InOut")
    With pvt

        With .PivotFields("Type")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
            .PivotItems("Total Workforce").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("NEW HIRES").Caption = "In"
            .PivotItems("SEPARATIONS").Caption = "Out"
        End With
        With .PivotFields("JobGroup")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .Position = 1
            .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
        End With
```

Code to create the second pivot table:

```
Set pvt = pvc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("AA1"), _
                        TableName:="OneYear_pvTbl_Sparkline")

    With pvt

        With .PivotFields("ExtractDate")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("White"), " White", xlSum
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Black"), " Black", xlSum
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Hispanic"), " Hispanic", xlSum
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Asian"), " Asian", xlSum
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("AmericanIndian"), " AmericanIndian", xlSum
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Male"), " Male", xlSum
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Female"), " Female", xlSum
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Total"), " Total", xlSum
    End With
```

Here is the code i got problem:
    'Create a hidden slicer to connect all pivot tables

```
    Dim SC As SlicerCache
    **Set SC = .SlicerCaches.Add(pvt, "JobGroup")**
    SC.Slicers.Add wk, , "JobGroup", "JobGroup", 50, 1000, 150, 200

    SC.PivotTables.AddPivotTable .Worksheets("Dashboard").PivotTables("OneYear_pvTbl_InOut")
```

I got an error message:

> run-time error'-2147418113'(8000ffff)':
>   Methods 'add' of object 'SlicerCaches' failed

Anyone can help?

Comment: The code i got the error is Set SC = .SlicerCaches.Add(pvt, "JobGroup")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SlicerCaches.Add` is not available at Office 2016.

Try with

```
Set SC = .SlicerCaches.Add2(pvt, "JobGroup")
```

Comment: I found the runtime error message when i test the code but it shows Automation error (Error 440) after i hit help. Is the  registry problem ?

Comment: Great it worked. I tested with that method and worked for me. Glad to know it.

Comment: But new problem just come up. The method worked once then failed again when i created another slicer. I tried to create it manually and recorded it as a macro but still same error. Do you know other method to create a slicer by VBA? Thanks!